# Do you use mysql_error($con) or mysql_insert_id($con) to check insert result?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-insert-id

```
$dml = "insert into table ...";
mysql_query($dml,$con);
```

The above insert something into a table.then you can check if it succeeded by either

```
if('' == mysql_error($con))...
```

or

```
if($id = mysql_insert_id($con))...
```

What's your choice and reason?

BTW,will the below still have $id fetched when running both of them,I've not tried yet:

```
$err = mysql_error($con);
$id = mysql_insert_id($con);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `mysql_error`.  I do so b/c it is more consistent with error checking in other parts of the program, and I will know why the error occurred instead of just receiving a false value.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_error()` will always throw an error if the insert operation fails, so fetching the insert_id is not really necessary as far as I can see, unless you need it for further processing.

Your code block should work, however the [**manual**](http://de.php.net/mysql_insert_id) recommends to run insert_id() directly after issuing the query.

> Note: Because mysql_insert_id() acts on the last performed query, be sure to call mysql_insert_id() immediately after the query that generates the value.

Comment: It depends on what `mysql_error` exactly does.I guess it probably won't bother MySQL to get error of last statement.